# How to check the presence of a file on the disk by the ID?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to check the presence of a file on the disk by the ID, and create a condition that if the file is on the disk then execute. DriveApp.getFileById(id) else ......

```js
function doGet(e){ 
  return handleResponse(e); 
} 

function doPost(e){ 
  return handleResponse(e); 
} 

function handleResponse(request) { 
  var fileid = request.parameter.fileid; 
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileid); 
  var subject = " subject"; 
  var htmlBody1 = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('mail_template'); 

  MailApp.sendEmail({ to: CUSTOMER_EMAIL, subject: subject, 
  htmlBody:htmlBody, attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)] }); 
}
```

The problem is that the ID is entered by the user in the form and comes to the script in the POST request, it is necessary to check the presence of the file on the disk, and if the file is present on the disk, attach to the letter and send, if there is no file then send an error message.

If the wrong ID arrives, the script stops executing DriveApp.getFileById(id).

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: var files = DriveApp.getFileById(ID);   if  (files.hasNext())                  but DriveApp.getFileById (ID) to if and if the ID incorrect script stops

Comment: Are you pulling the ID from a form submit somewhere? I'm just trying to understand the entire flow. Posting your script to the question itself would be helpful.

Comment: `function doGet(e){
return handleResponse(e);
}
function doPost(e){
return handleResponse(e);
  }
 function handleResponse(request) {
 var fileid = request.parameter.fileid;
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileid);
 
 var subject = " subject";
    var htmlBody1 = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('mail_template');
   
     MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: CUSTOMER_EMAIL,
     subject: subject,
     htmlBody: htmlBody,
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)] 
   });
  
}
`